# Google Map Locatin by name in php

Tags: javascript, php, google-maps, vs-web-site-project

Friends,
I'm novice in googlmap api I want to use google maps to show location of places, while I only have places names in database, basically I want to put a marker on the given name of location in database.
I'm using php, mysql, javascript.
thanks.

Comment: Okay, what have you tried so far?

Comment: @Epodax I'm searching way as I don't have prior knowledge of google map usage. So I'm still learning ways and searching. haven't done anything else.

Comment: SO isn't going to code it for you, give it a try yourself and come back if you run into a error. (And no, we can't offer guides / How-to's either, it's off-topic).

Answer (score 0):

You could use an iframe with the Google Maps url in it. In that url, you can add a database value by a php variable. Don't forget you need a google api key!

An example iframe:

```
<iframe
  width="600"
  height="450"
  frameborder="0" style="border:0"
  src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed/v1/place?q=Brugge,+België&key=...">
</iframe>
```

In php, you could add a dynamic database value into the url after 'q'. An example:

```
<?php
    echo '<iframe
       width="600"
       height="450"
       frameborder="0" style="border:0"
       src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed/v1/place?q=' .placevariable. '&key=...">
    </iframe>';
?>
```

Comment: Dear Thanks for your reply,
i have tried given code but it says `The Google Maps API server rejected your request. Invalid request. Invalid 'q' parameter.`
again thanks for your reply

Comment: ow, ofcourse, you don't need the "" in the src. I will update the answer.

Comment: Dear Freind I'm getting api key rejection  I'm trying to get api key which I got is not working I'm getting key for  Google Maps Embed API. with Thanks dear I'm grateful to your help

Comment: you could try this wizard. It then give you the chance to create an api key: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/embed/start?hl=nl

Comment: Thanks It helped a lot.
friend in my problem scenario I have to show multiple places  while iframe can display only one place